# .NET Scheduled Method Invokation

Tags: .net, wpf, .net-3.5

Have some runtime defined schedule for one week, for example:

```
<schedule>
    <s day="Monday", time="1:00:00"></s>
    <s day="Sunday", time="3:00:00"></s>
    <s day="Wednsday", time="16:00:00"></s>
    ...
    ...
</schdule>
```

On that time i have to call some method.
Is there any built in class in .net/wpf for this purpose?
Or any opensource/free controls?
Or best way is to initialize new timer for each element?

**Edit:** WPF application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing built-in .NET. You could initialize a [Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx) for each element. If you are looking for third party components, you may checkout [Quartz.NET](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution could be using a Task Scheduler, so Windows can manage tasks without the need for your software to run in background (as a service?!?).
A good starting point could be [Task Scheduler Class Library for .NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2407/A-New-Task-Scheduler-Class-Library-for-NET).